# Connection in c# app does not timeout when Poolling = true on Firebird 2.5.6

Tags: c#, .net, database, database-connection, firebird

When I use a connection string with `Pooling=true` on my c# app to connect to Firebird 2.5.6 SuperServer, and I disconnect from network, then

```
FbConnection fbc = new FbConnection(connstring);
```

`fbc.Open()` - does not ever timeout, can wait very long and it is deadlocked here.

But when I use connection string with `Pooling = false`, then it's ok, after few seconds code goes to next line.

Also when I use `Pooling = True` and before `.Open()` I do:

```
FbConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

than its is also ok - after few seconds code goes to next line.

Why with `pooling = true`, I have this deadlock if not clear all pools before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem does not seem to be a deadlock, but rather a problem of blocking (probably on network I/O).

When you use `Pooling=true`, the Firebird ADO.net Provider keeps the physical connection to the server open for reuse. Only the handle used in your code gets closed. When you open a 'new' connection, it will first try to get a physical connection from the pool and hand it to you (maybe doing some validation), and if there is no connection in the pool, it will create a new physical connection.

If you disconnect from the network, the existing connection may still be open but no longer work. Attempting to write to the connection may either succeed (because of buffers) or block, attempts to read may block as well. How long this blocking lasts depends on a number of factors (how the disconnect occurred, configuration of networking, socket timeouts, etc). This may mean that reads or writes can block indefinitely when trying to use a socket that was already open at the time the disconnect occurred. If the network connection is restored, existing connections may either start working again or may really be broken, but again, depending on the nature of the disconnect, it can take some time to recover or actually fail.

On the other hand, using `Pooling=false` will make sure that each `FbConnection.Open()` will create a new physical connection, and similarly, `FbConnection.ClearAllPools()` will remove and close existing physical connections in the pool, forcing a new physical connection to be needed on a subsequent call to `FbConnection.Open()`.

Now when this new physical connection is created, the network stack will - usually - detect very quickly that the remote server is not accessible, and fail quickly, or - if the network connection has been restored - will just be able to connect quickly.

Unfortunately, the Firebird ADO.net Provider does not seem to specify either `SendTimeout` or `ReceiveTimeout` on its socket, which means there is no way to make it fail faster in the absence of a working socket connection.

Comment: thanks, so if i need fast notification of network errors i should use pooling = false?

Comment: @user2265690 Looks like it, yes. The alternative would be to open a ticket (or create a pull request) to add a socket read/write timeout.

Comment: or eventually create connection in separate (for non blocking gui behaviour ) thread and if in specified time it will not return, use it as error?

Comment: @user2265690 You could do that, but personally I think this is a 'problem' that should be solved in the driver.